# Java Sql Date cast to DateWritable

Tags: java, date, hive

```
   commonEDWUDFManager.ROUND(expression.toString(), format)
                    .getTime()
```

is giving the output 1901-01-01 in java.util.Date format

```
   Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(commonEDWUDFManager.ROUND(expression.toString(), format.getTime());

    System.out.println(sqlDate);
```

output 1901-01-01

```
    DateWritable dateWritable = new DateWritable(sqlDate);
    System.out.println(dateWritable);
```

output 1901-01-02

When I cast java.sql.Date to DateWritable it is changing the Date.
I want to know why?

Comment: and your problem is ?

Comment: what is your expression you use as input? does it contain timezone information?

Comment: No it does not contain any Timezone information.
It is in Text format.

Comment: The output in java.util.Date format is "Tue Jan 01 16:40:23 IST 1901"